Mounted host directory not writable for custom user despite consistent uid
I have a docker image that sets a custom USER, and am mounting a host directory whose owner has the same user id as the custom USER (as suggested here). Still, I cannot write to the host directory from the docker image.
I have run into this problem many times with pre-built docker images, but I am reproducing a minimal example here.
Simple Dockerfile using a custom USER:
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash mydockeruser

USER mydockeruser

Trying to touch a file on the host:
docker run -it \
    -v ./my-directory:/host \
    my-ubuntu \
    touch /host/test.txt

# touch: cannot touch '/host/test.txt': Permission denied

My installation
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and Docker version 27.3.1, build ce12230, and I installed rootless docker by following the official instructions, most importantly by running dockerd-rootless-setuptool.sh install.
Maybe the issue is due to uid remapping by rootless docker?
Not a duplicate
This question is not a duplicate, because it was due to a mismatch between the custom user id (in the image) and the owner of the mounted directory (on the host).
Details
Here is a full script which shows my situation, and also shows the relevant uids:
echo "Building my-ubuntu:"
docker build -t my-ubuntu .

# [+] Building 0.6s (6/6) FINISHED
# [...]

########
# HOST #
########

rm -rf my-directory
mkdir my-directory

echo "$ ls -la my-directory:"
ls -la my-directory

# total 8
# drwxrwxr-x 2 myhostuser myhostuser 4096 Oct  7 15:01 .
# drwxrwxr-x 3 myhostuser myhostuser 4096 Oct  7 15:01 ..

echo "$ id:"
id

# uid=1000(myhostuser) gid=1000(myhostuser) groups=1000(myhostuser),[...]

##########
# DOCKER #
##########

echo "$ id (inside my-ubuntu):"
docker run -it \
    -v ./my-directory:/host \
    my-ubuntu \
    id

# uid=1000(mydockeruser) gid=1000(mydockeruser) groups=1000(mydockeruser)

echo "$ touch /host/test.txt (inside my-ubuntu):"
docker run -it \
    -v ./my-directory:/host \
    my-ubuntu \
    touch /host/test.txt

# touch: cannot touch '/host/test.txt': Permission denied


Either find the numeric user ID of the container user and sudo chown the host directory to that user, or find the numeric user ID of the host user and docker run -u the container with that user ID.  At the end you mention a rootless setup and if there's any user ID remapping that can complicate the setup.

@DavidMaze Thanks for the suggestion! I believe the uid is already correct, and have added further details that also explain why the marked duplicate does not seem to apply in my case. I also included your reasonable guess that this could be a "rootless docker" issue.

Yes, it's the expected behavior of volume mounts when you run docker rootless. You'd see your user in the container is not the same as the user on the host, and file ownership of the mounted directory inside the container does not match the host, because everything is shifted to a different user namespace.
